# Set Facebook Profile Picture and Coverphoto C# SDK

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, facebook-c#-sdk

I am working on a Windows Phone 8 photo app. With that app a user can login with his Facebook account and set profile picture and cover photo programatically from that app. I am searching for a way to do this but couldnt find. Can anyone help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the profile picture using Facebook API.What you can do is allow user to upload a photo to their album and then redirect to change profile picture link..
Check out this link http://4rapiddev.com/facebook-graph-api/php-change-facebook-profile-picture-with-graph-api/ 
This is for using PHP SDK, the procedure should be same in .NET SDK too.